# Electric Bidet Toilet seat started tripping GFCI

Tags: electrical

I have an electric bidet toilet seat that plugs into the GFCI outlet in my bathroom. After about 6 months it started tripping the GFCI instantly upon being plugged in.  Does this mean the toilet seat has an electrical problem?  If the toilet seat works on a non-GFCI outlet would it be safe to use one?  I am afraid of electrified water being shot at my rectum. Would the normal ground wire be enough to prevent any  danger?

Comment: Ground wire doesn't do much good here, that's why they put GFCIs in bathrooms.

Comment: @FreeMan yes It turned out that there was a short in floating ring sensor that detects water level in the tank.  I replaced the sensor and it was fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It broke

My bet? The appliance is tripping the GFCI *because the appliance has a ground fault*.  Shocking, I know, right?  I'd have a qualified technician examine it for signs of what went wrong, or replace it outright if repair is not an option.

Comment: Is it safe to use in the mean time with a non-GFCI outlet?

Comment: @Alex -- I would say "no" -- probably better to give up the luxury than risk a zap...

Comment: I'd try to run a 3 prong extension cord from another gfci in the house to see if it trips as well. If it trips, then it's highly probable that it's the seat. If it doesn't trip, replace the outlet near the toilet.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not plug the seat into a non GFCI receptacle.

Answer (score 2):

My smartbidet kept tripping kept tripping gfci. I took it apart and found two 47micro farad 250 bolt capacitors blown. After replacing the two capacitors it worked fine. You ca tell a blown capacitor by the top of the can, which is cross cut, is buldging up and is not flat.